# How does Visual Studio create and run a docker container?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

We are in the process of migrating one of our .net core 2.1 applications into a linux container. At first, I used Visual Studio to create the container for me, with its built-in support for turning your project into an executable docker file. This worked perfectly fine in Visual Studio, launching the project and running it exactly as expected. The issues begin when we started to port the project over into Azure Devops.

To my knowledge, we have to run the container via the CLI, and we do so with the docker build command. This started revealing errors we hadn't seen running through VS. The first error was our private repo, we had to add a nuget config with a clear text password to restore the project. After we resolved that error, we started seeing more DLLs that were missing (such as Microsoft.CSharp) and error messages such as: "`Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. Assembly file could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata.`"

It is at this point that I decided to take a step back and try to research how VS built the container and see if it would be possible to change how we build the container. The issue is I cannot find a lot of documentation on the subject, and none of it covers how I could replicate running through VS in the command line. What I hope to get from this is the exact steps VS uses to give a docker container my credentials for nuget, and how it builds the container, since it obviously does not work the same as `docker build .`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019 but share your dockerfile please

Comment: The documentation is either missing a piece of the puzzle or is inaccurate. I can post a generic dockerfile, but my specific dockerfile is irrelevant as the file is only created by VS. This question is about the steps/config VS does behind the scenes to run the files, rather than any specific issue with the file.